# How can I use DayOfWeek enum to flag process cycles?

Tags: vb.net, enums, dayofweek

In app.config, I supply a *cycle* string value: "Monday", "Tuesday", ..., "Daily". From that value I wanted to assign a `<Flags()>` enum. Simply using `DayOfWeek` does not give me the ability to flag a process as a daily routine. Is there an available .Net class that does provide the day of week as a flag?

In the meantime, I devised the following:

```
<Flags()> _
Public Enum enumExportCycle As Integer
    Monday = DayOfWeek.Monday
    Tuesday = DayOfWeek.Tuesday
    Wednesday = DayOfWeek.Wednesday + 1
    Thursday = DayOfWeek.Thursday + 4
    Friday = DayOfWeek.Friday + 11
    Saturday = DayOfWeek.Saturday + 26
    Sunday = DayOfWeek.Sunday + 64
    Daily = Monday Or Tuesday Or Wednesday Or Thursday Or Friday Or Saturday Or Sunday
End Enum
```

It feels somewhat hackish and I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will work, right?

```
<Flags()> _
Public Enum enumExportCycle As Integer
    Monday = 1
    Tuesday = 2
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 8
    Friday = 16
    Saturday = 32
    Sunday = 64
    Daily = Monday Or Tuesday Or Wednesday Or Thursday Or Friday Or Saturday Or Sunday
End Enum
```

or this

```
<Flags()> _
Public Enum enumExportCycle As Integer
    Monday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Monday
    Tuesday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Tuesday
    Wednesday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Wednesday
    Thursday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Thursday
    Friday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Friday
    Saturday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Saturday
    Sunday = 2 ^ DayOfWeek.Sunday
    Daily = Monday Or Tuesday Or Wednesday Or Thursday Or Friday Or Saturday Or Sunday
End Enum
```

since DayOfWeek start from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday)

Comment: sometimes the simplest solutions are the most difficult to see. I'm in the forest and can't find a tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a link to a DaysOfWeek enum (used for setting recurrences) for PocketOutlook on Windows Mobile:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.daysofweek.aspx

It defines an enum like this:

```
[Flags] 
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
  Sunday = 1,
  Monday = 2,
  Tuesday = 4,
  Wednesday = 8,
  Thursday = 16,
  Friday = 32,
  Saturday = 64
}
```

I would define a similar enum with an additional one for Daily (and maybe for every weekday and every weekend day:

```
[Flags] 
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
  Sunday = 1,
  Monday = 2,
  Tuesday = 4,
  Wednesday = 8,
  Thursday = 16,
  Friday = 32,
  Saturday = 64,
  Daily = Sunday + Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday + Saturday,
  Weekdays = Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday,
  Weekends = Sunday + Saturday
}
```

Comment: great idea for weekdays and weekends

Comment: @IAbstract yeah, never thought of that. +1